# How to pass the /unsafe flag to the C# compiler when building an SSDT Project with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

**Prefix:**
Please let's no get all tangled up in `should I do this`, nor if it is supported. Microsoft provide the `Unsafe` permission set for exactly this purpose

> A CLR assembly created with PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE may be able to
>   access external system resources, ***call unmanaged code***, and acquire
>   sysadmin privileges.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-assembly-transact-sql

**Now, onto the question:**

So, conventional wisdom holds that, when one wishes to use an unsafe code block such as

```
  unsafe {
     fixed (char* passwordChars = password) {
        var securePassword = new SecureString(passwordChars, password.Length);
        securePassword.MakeReadOnly();
        return securePassword;
     }
  }
```

One simply checks the checkbox in the **Build** options and off one trots:

[image: CSProj Build Options]

However, I'm at a total loss to understand how one does it when one's building a SSDT `SqlProj` project. Here's the build (**SQLCLR Build**) options for that project type:

[image: SqlProj Build Options]

So, aside from the usual *"Danger, Danger, Will Robinson"* type warnings, is this even possible with a `SqlProj` project type? And yes, I am building unsafe code and yes, I am signing the code, using an asymmetric key and login with `Unsafe` rights attached to it.

All that aside, how the heck you pass this onto the compiler command line? Also, I'm not against modifying the `sqlproj` file if that's what it takes.

**Thoughts**

If I *have* to I suppose I might be able create another assembly, outside of the `SqlProj` format with this code in and load that to Sql Server as an assembly that I then reference. It just seems odd that the `SqlProj` project format specifically prohibits this flag being set.

Comment: I expect it is not possible.

Comment: At the end of the day, it's a compiler flag - surely there *has* to be a way to pass that in, even outside of the confines of Visual Studio. Unsure as to legalities of such an op, but this is what I'd like to know.

Comment: But what is SSDT project? I expect if it runs in a special environment, it is quite normal that native unsafe code is not alled in there.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, the option to pass to the compiler is [`/unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/unsafe-compiler-option). I don't know if the compiler options can be twiddled from wthin the `.sqlproj`; manually building the code is always possible, but deploying it as part of the project may be tricky. `unsafe` appears to be unnecessary here, though. Unless you've already shown this to be a perf hotspot, you can call `.AppendChar` in a loop in a safe context.

Comment: "It just seems odd that the SqlProj project format specifically prohibits this flag being set." Are you kidding? This code is going to run *inside the SQL Server process*. They'd be mad if they just exposed this option, IMO.

Comment: All due respecr @JeroenMostert, my post title clearly states I know I need to pass /unsafe. In addition, if you look at my code, I'm using pointers, hence the need for the `unsafe` code block - and this is just one example - there are others.

Comment: Thanks, @AlKepp, however SSDT compiles code to deploy in Sql Server. At the end of the day I don't even HAVE to do that per say, it just provides a framework for certain outputs. My main codeset is already deployed to Sql Server as an assembly and that was just a normal `csproj` project type.

Comment: You're getting that pointer by pinning a managed block of data, so I assumed (correct me if I'm wrong) that you actually have managed memory you can read in a managed way. Unsafe code is almost never *necessary* to get work done in .NET, it's just faster (under some circumstances). A `SecureString` isn't a particularly compelling example of that, so if that were the only instance of unsafe code, there'd be a strong argument for just rewriting that code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm using `SecureString` and need to marshal data in it. And, as I said, this was just one such example, I have others. So please can we focus on the needs of the question, and not suggestions on how I should write my code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - that's why they allow the `External Access` and `Unsafe` permissions for assemblies. And there's NOTHING stopping me from doing that to a normal assembly that I deploy to Sql Server. So let's keep the veiled insults to zero and focus on the issue at hand. As per MS's OWN documentation: **A CLR assembly created with PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE may be able to access external system resources, ***call unmanaged code***, and acquire sysadmin privileges.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157755/discussion-between-rachel-ambler-and-jeroen-mostert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI will not expose the option, but the project file still supports it (along with any other option you can pass to the compiler).

In VS,  right-click the project and choose "Unload Project", then right-click again and choose "Edit project". In the main `<PropertyGroup>` block, add

```
<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
```

Save, reload  the project once more, and it should now build `unsafe` blocks without complaint.

Note that `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE` is much broader than what C# calls "unsafe". Even doing something in verified managed code that might nevertheless compromise the stability or throughput of the engine (like threading) is prohibited under `PERMISSION_SET = SAFE` (prior to Code Access Security getting abandoned and complicating things a lot, that is).